# how to print all groups or usernames for a given folder using c++

Tags: c++, winapi, acl, dacl

I have some problem. I tried to search solving in the internet, but didn't find them (they didn't work).

The problem is...

For example I have some folder: "directory1", I must get usernames and their permissions regarding this folder..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your questions to improve them, like showing us a [mre] of your own attempt together with a description of the problems you have with it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

[Finding the Owner of a File Object in C++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/finding-the-owner-of-a-file-object-in-c--) example uses the GetSecurityInfo and LookupAccountSid functions to find and print the name of the owner of a file.
[GetSecurityInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/aclapi/nf-aclapi-getsecurityinfo#remarks) also can retrieve [The primary group of an object, The discretionary access control list (DACL) of an object, The system access control list (SACL) of an object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/security-information).

Comment: i tried but i dont know how to declare HANDLE for folder path

Comment: [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew#parameters) can open a path.

Comment: i want to print the folder security information. if i use the createfile i got a error. create file Error = 5.

Comment: According to [CreateFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew#directories), To open a directory using **CreateFile**, specify the **FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS** flag as part of *dwFlagsAndAttributes*.